# Datagridview not reflecting dataset changes

Tags: datagridview, dataset

I created a datagridview with a dataset as its data source. On the keydown event of a certain textbox i add a new line to the dataset and it is direclty reflected in the datagridview. But if i happen to click on the final row in the datagridview "the one with the star on its left" no matter how many lines i add to the dataset they wont be reflected. If i return the count of the dataset rows i can see that they are added only they are no more reflected in the datagridview. I tried ds.acceptchanges and datagridview.refresh but non helped. Any solution?

Here is the code i used:

```
if ds.tables(0).rows(datagridview.rows.count-1).item("Amount")<>0 then
ds.tables(0).rows.add(ds.tables(0).newrow)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, First of all, you should use a Binding Source. This is what makes your DataGridView & DataTable as one.

First Thing to do is this :-

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```

Now you need to setup the Datasource for your DatagridView, which will be your BindingSource bs :-

```
DatagridView1.Datasource = bs;
```

Now any changes made in your DatagridView will automatically reflect in your DataSet Table. It also means that any changes made in the DataTable will automatically reflect in your GridView.

Comment: this is already done, this why i find this error really weird, coz the binding is working fine until u click on  the last row the one with the star * to its left

Comment: You could try changing the "KeyDown" event so that it adds a row to the DataGridView as opposed to the DataTable, as the two objects are Bound it should reflect the changes back to the DataSet.